# Apply JSONPath filter to field with space

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I'm trying to use JSONPath (https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) to search a document which has spaces in the field names:

```
{
  "model": {
    "Details": {
      "Nospace": "New today",
      "Random nonsense": "New today"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm testing using the evaluator at http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

This works:

```
$.model.Details[?(@.Nospace== 'New today')]
```

But this does not:

```
$.model.Details[?(@.'Random nonsense'== 'New today')]
```

This does but is missing the filter expression:

```
$.model.Details['Random nonsense']
```

So it seems it's possible to refer to fields with spaces, but I haven't found how to use them in a filter.  Is it possible?   I have tried many other combinations with no luck, and don't seem to find anything online about it either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extra brackets.

```
$.model.Details[?(@['Random nonsense'] == 'New today')]
```