# How do I get the value of a key that contains a space in Rest Assured and is child of another key?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I need to get the keys from my backend api using Rest Assured, but most of them are children of another key and have spaces in between, so don't know how to get them?

```
{
 "success": true,
 "nav": {
    "Settings": "/application/settings/personal",
    "Notification Preferences": "/application/settings/notifications",
    "Reset Password": "/application/settings/reset-password",
    "logout": "/application/logout"
 }
}
```

It's very similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112425/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-key-if-it-contains-a-space-in-rest-assured-serenit) but in that case the key wasn't a child of another key. I'm trying to make something like this to work:

```
.body("'nav.Reset Password'", equalTo("#"))
```

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: What json library do you use?

Comment: Hi @ihsankocak, thanks for your reply. It's version 20090211, rest-assured 3.1.0 and json-simple 1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below snippet will fix your problem.

```
.body("nav.'Reset Password'", equalTo("#"));
```

Have to give single quotes for the key only which have space like `nav.'Reset Password'`. You have given single quotes for complete path(`'nav.Reset Password'` ) this is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi @Veeresh, thanks very much for your answer. It worked. :)

Comment: Oh great ... Welcome:)