# Unable to get value of key with spaces using JsonPath library

Tags: java, rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm using [Json Path](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path/3.0.0) library to parse JSON. I've following json which has key with space:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "First Name": "Jim",
        "Last Name": "Rohn"
    }
}
```

In order to get value of `First Name`, I wrote code like (where `json` is object which holds above json) -

```
String firstName = JsonPath.from(json).getString("attributes.First Name");
```

But it results into following error -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found 'Attributes' @ line 1, column 67.
   .First Name
```

Could you please suggest how to get values of key having spaces using `json-path` library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using bracket notation for `First Name` as follows:

```
String firstName = JsonPath.from(json).getString("attributes.['First Name']");
```

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry for mixing different `JsonPath` libraries up.

If you are using `com.jayway.jsonpath`, try following way for escaping:

```
DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(json);
String firstName = jsonContext.read("$.attributes.['First Name']");
```

But if you are using `***.restassured.json-path`, please use this one:

```
String firstName = JsonPath.from(json).getString("attributes.'First Name'");
```

Comment: I've used `io.rest-assured.rest-assured.4.1.2` which internally uses `io.rest-assured.json-path.4.1.2`

Comment: @TDHM So does the solution in this post [How do I get the value of a key if it contains a space in Rest Assured / Serenity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45112425/6469772) also not help?

Comment: Thanks a lot man it helped! It should be like `attributes.'First Name'`

Comment: @TDHM Great! I have updated my post, please check it out!

Comment: Thanks
I was stuck in this but not it works.
return_reason_(l1) this key was the issue
$.order_details[0].return_items[0].return_reasons[0]['return_reason_(l1)'].code

Answer (score 1):

You  have to escape the key with single quotes

Use below code:

```
String firstName = JsonPath.from(json).getString("'attributes.First Name'");
```

Comment: This does not give any error but returns `null` as a value even though there is non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath** library then Escape Sequences is required in the path expression.

```
String firstName = JsonPath.from(json).getString("attributes.\"First Name\"");

\" <-- Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
```

So your path expression looks like `(attributes."First Name")` and can be parsed by JsonPath library